# SMTP Email Send Using Hostinger Email

Tags: php, email, smtp

```
function send_email($receiver_email,$subject,$message)
{
      $mail = new PHPMailer;

      $mail->IsSMTP();

      $mail->Host = 'smtp.hostinger.com';

      $mail->Port = '465';

      $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
      
      $mail->SMTPDebug = 2; 

      $mail->Username = 'support@kachandarululoomnijamiamadrasah.org';

      $mail->Password = 'EmailPassowrd';

      $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';

      $mail->From = 'support@kachandarululoomnijamiamadrasah.org';

      $mail->FromName = 'Kachan Darul Uloom Nijamia Madrasah';

      $mail->AddAddress($receiver_email, '');

      $mail->IsHTML(true);

      $mail->Subject = $subject;

      $mail->Body = $message;

      $mail->header='MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";

      $mail->header.='Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
      
      //$mail->AddEmbeddedImage('first.png','apple');

      if($mail->Send())
      {
        return true;
      }
      else
      {
        return "{$mail->ErrorInfo}";
      }
        
}
```

In this Upper  code i want to Send email Uding Hostinger  Free Business Email  but When i am use this details & use this code Than make an error  not send email & send me "SMTP connect() failed." error Message

How Can i resolved the problem

Can you make me resolved this problem

Please help me

Comment: First thing to check : Make sure your SMTP password is correct and port 465 is not blocked

Comment: One further point : According to [official documentation](https://support.hostinger.com/en/articles/4305847-set-up-hostinger-email-on-your-applications-and-devices) -- if you encounter SMTP encryption issues, use TLS or STARTTLS with port 587 instead.